# mlUnittest is throwing error in MarkLogic

Tags: gradle, xquery, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

Mlunittest is throwing error while running as a gradle comment and I am getting below error

> Local message: failed to read resource at resources/marklogic-unit-test: Internal Server Error. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request:  reason: Extension marklogic-unit-test or a dependency does not exist: XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /marklogic.rest.resource/marklogic-unit-test/assets/resource.xqy not found

I am using:

- MarkLogic 9.0-12 version
- Gradle 4.3.1
- DHF  4.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message suggests that the marklogic-unit-test libraries are not being loaded into the modules database correctly.  If you're using ml-gradle to manage your modules you may want to double check your `build.gradle` file, specifically that marklogic-unit-test is configured as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
  mlBundle "com.marklogic:marklogic-unit-test-modules:1.0.0"
}
```

You can check out a similar issue that was filed with the marklogic-unit-test and how it was resolved here: https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-unit-test/issues/86

For a more complete example of a `build.gradle` file that imports marklogic-unit-test into a project check out the marklogic-unit-test project at https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-unit-test#start-using-marklogic-unit-test.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" error now while running mlunittest